# How to pass the SSH_AUTH_SOCK through sudo (Permission denied (publickey).)

Tags: ssh, sudo, public-key, permissions

I have a Ubuntu server with the users: `ubuntu` and `user`

I connect to each of the users using `ssh -A` (to pass my local machine keys to SSH). From **any** of the users I can connect to the SSH server of Github:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
...
Hi gabipetrovay! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But when I try to connect from `ubuntu` using `sudo`, on behalf of `user`

```
sudo -E -u user ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

Using the `-vv` option for `ssh` I can see that when running with sudo on behalf of `user` from `ubuntu` the key on my machine is not offered to the ssh server. As a comparison:

directly form `user`:

```
debug2: key: /Users/gabriel/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fbf09390020),
debug2: key: /home/mono/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/mono/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/mono/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/mono/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
```

from `ubuntu` using `sudo -u user`:

```
debug2: key: /home/mono/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/mono/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/mono/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/mono/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
```

So it seems that through `sudo` the SSH_AUTH_SOCK socket is not considered.

I have also added `Defaults env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to `/etc/sudoers` but it still does not work.

How can I achieve this? I need to execute `ssh` and `git` commands from user `ubuntu` on behalf of the `user` user.

Comment: What does the command: `sudo -u user -E env | grep SSH_AUTH_SOCK` return?

Comment: It returns a socket: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-IiZzBuvPc9/agent.1148`

Comment: Ok, so your ssh command is getting the environment variable correctly. I suspect that the permissions on the SSH_AUTH_SOCK file  is preventing access from `user`. Can you try `chown user $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` before running `sudo -E -u user ssh -T git@github.com`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to adding `Defaults env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to `sudoers`, you also need to give your `user` access to file pointed by SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable. It is not enabled by default.